# Is there any way redis can check conditions before expiring keys via TTL?

Tags: redis

Consider I have a very large records(key values) of data in redis for which the TTL is set according to some business rules(also stored in redis), lets say if the business rule is changed, and because of that the record should not expire on the time which it was set previously, but should expire according to new time.
I cannot simply change the ttl of millions of records, each time the rule is updated.
How can I acheive this ? Is there a way in redis, which allows us to provide a script to run when it deletes the record when TTL is met.

Answer (score 0):

Redis supports LUA scripting. Maybe you should check it.

https://redis.io/commands/eval/

EVAL         : Executes a Lua script.

EVALSHA       : Executes a Lua script. Cached

SCRIPT EXISTS : Check in the script cache by hash

SCRIPT FLUSH  : Clear cache

SCRIPT KILL   : Kill running script

SCRIPT LOAD   : Loads the specified Lua script into the script cache.

```
redis 127.0.0.1:6379> EVAL "return {KEYS[1],KEYS[2],ARGV[1],ARGV[2]}" 2 key1
key2 first second
1) "key1"
2) "key2"
3) "first"
4) "second"
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/33134277)

Comment: You right, I added some little explanation about scripting and executing